# xsl to produce summation value for each attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, sum

I want to use XSLT to calculate the summation value of amount

the input is:

```
<FileHeader>
    <Item amount="500" />                  
    <Item amount="600" />                  
    <Item amount="400" />                  
    <Item amount="700" />                  
    <Item amount="100" />                  
    <Item amount="900" />                  
    <Item amount="1000" />                 
    <Item amount="200" />                  
    <Item amount="700" />                  
</FileHeader>
```

The output should be:

```
<Result>
  <FileSummary TotalAmount="5100">
</Result>
```

Thanks,

Comment: It's a typo. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196985/232821

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Result>
    <FileSummary TotalAmount="{sum(/FileHeader/Item/@amount)}" />
</Result>
```

Tested. Fixed typo. This should work.

Comment: it worked thanks :) just with typo error: "Item" instead of "Iteam"

Comment: no problem :) I found the information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256160.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how this can be done:
[XSLT: Sum of products from multiple nodes](http://blog.davidkaspar.com/archives/2003/10/xslt-sum-of-products-from-multiple-nodes.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<Result>
  <FileSummary>
      <xsl:attribute name="TotalAmount">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(//FileHeader/Item/@amount)" />
      </xsl:attribute>
  </FileSummary>
</Result>
```

Comment: Note that the `//` operator should be avoided as long as possible. Its performance is bad, especially as the input documents get larger.