# XSLT 2.0 Sum of values considered as string

Tags: string, sum, xslt-2.0

I am confronted to what I thought it was a simple problem but I am stuck.
Here is an xml data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report endDate="2013/02/01 15:10:14" environment="Q000" startDate="2013/01/25 15:10:14">
<distrib appCode="LI" busLine="IL" context="" id="2013-01-25-15.10.11.785293" network="FBB" subNetwork="Z">
  <deliv id="2013-01-25-15.10.11.785295" mode="1" role="">
     <comm id="2013-01-25-15.10.11.785297" role="">
        <group id="001">
           <doc id="950955269" nbPages="1" templateId="LVMED1" />
        </group>
        <group id="002">
           <doc id="950955270" nbPages="6" templateId="BALVANW_FA" />
        </group>
        <group id="003">
           <doc id="950955271" nbPages="" templateId="LVMED23" />
        </group>
     </comm>
  </deliv>
</distrib>
<distrib appCode="LI" busLine="IL" context="" id="2013-01-25-15.18.29.871466" network="FBB" subNetwork="Z">
  <deliv id="2013-01-25-15.18.29.871468" mode="1" role="">
     <comm id="2013-01-25-15.18.29.871469" role="">
        <group id="001">
           <doc id="950955331" nbPages="2" templateId="LVMED10" />
        </group>
     </comm>
  </deliv>
</distrib>
</report>
```

I would like to sum the content of attributes nbPages in elements 'doc'

Here is the xslt I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="report">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(//doc)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(//doc[@nbPages])"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The count works well, but the sum does not.

**[Saxon-PE 9.3.0.5] Cannot convert string {} to a double**

I have tried using the following alternatives without success:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(number(//doc[@nbPages]))"/>
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//doc[number(@nbPages)])"/>
```

Any help would be very appreciated on this.

Answer (score 4):

**Use**:

```
sum(//doc/@nbPages[number(.) = number(.)])
```

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="sum(//doc/@nbPages[number(.) = number(.)])"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**producing the correct result**:

```
9
```

Comment: Great! This also works for nodes that represent a number: `this/node/here/number(.)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your XPATH is wrong for sum function.

Since

`//doc[@nbPages]` : This XPath returns nodes, not the values of `nbPages` attribute.

Do it this way:-

`//doc[not(@nbPages) or @nbPages!='']/@nbPages` : This XPath checks that the `nbPages` attributes exists and is not empty.

```
sum(//doc[not(@nbPages) or @nbPages!='']/@nbPages)

<xsl:value-of select="sum(//doc[not(@nbPages) or @nbPages!='']/@nbPages)"/>
```

### XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="report">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(//doc)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(//doc[not(@nbPages) or @nbPages!='']/@nbPages)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have indeed misconfused the use of [] operator :-/

Comment: @user2032839: If you think, answer is helpful. You need click **Tick mark** on the left side of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath expression like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//doc/@nbPages)"/>
```

Same issue is here: 
[xsl summation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815348/xsl-to-produce-summation-value-for-each-attribute)

Comment: Yes except it does not work if @nbPages is empty. We need to check this like showed in first answer.